# Dock in Ubuntu MATE (*not* GNOME 3) hides behind full-screen apps

Tags: mate, 21.10, dock

MATE is a gnome 2.0 derivative, so none of the solutions I've read that involve running a shell-extension such as "dash-to-dock" will work on MATE. MATE Tweaks has but one checkbox "Enable dock" under panel. How to make it pop up when I move mouse cursor to bottom of screen? Looks like its only two behaviors are: 1) hidden when an app is full-screen in foreground; and 2) displayed otherwise. I have used docks in other desktops (gnome 3) and the "popup" behavior is one I'd like to see in MATE, which I overall prefer to the gnome 3 and KDE approaches.

Comment: FYI:   MATE may have started as a GNOME 2.0 derivative; but it's not been that for *many* years !   It's GTK3 and had ported to GTK3 prior to Ubuntu-MATE 16.04 with little of the original code remaining. It's an *actively* developed desktop so it's origins are little more than history now.

Comment: Ah, good info, I was misled by a recent article that apparently was also misinformed. Plank support may assist me further with this issue, interesting that changing desktop *theme* in MATE will cause all the dock settings to be reset. Thanks @guiverc for the update!

Comment: seems like this author should be apprised of this information, too: https://itsfoss.com/best-linux-desktop-environments/ See MATE review.

Answer (score 0):

Install plank and the option to enable dock will be activated.

1. Open terminal and run `sudo apt install plank`.
2. Then open `mate-tweak` and go to the panel section.
3. Select *Enable dock*. And you will get a Mac OS like dock.

To customize plank, open terminal and run `plank --preferences`